# Setting cell formula with c# in excel file including %

Tags: c#, excel

You can set formula like this in an excel file using c#:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula = "=$A$4+$A$10";
```

If the formula contains % then an error occurs (a table column name contains %). How can you use % in formula?

The code:

```
   errorFormula = @"=ISBLANK([@[Nettó hozam(évesített %)]])";
   Excel.Range cell = accountSheet.Cells[idxI, columnId];
   cell.Formula = errorFormula;
```

Error happens at excecution, and the formula is not added to the excel file: Error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

The % sign is just part of a column name. If I reference to other table columns, which does not contain %, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I realized my error had nothing to do with %. The correct formula was:

```
@"=ISBLANK([@[Nettó hozam (évesített %)]])"
```

and not

```
@"=ISBLANK([@[Nettó hozam(évesített %)]])"
```

One space was missing!